# [AngularJS][Ionic] Make Controller wait for Service that uses another $http service

Tags: angularjs, promise, ionic-framework

The problem is that Controller doesn't wait for Service that uses another $http service, and I get no data.

services.js:

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])
    .factory('Likes', function ($http) {
        var likes;
        $http.get("http://localhost:8100/js/offers.json")
                .success(function (results) {
                    likes = results.offers;
                    console.log("ok!");
                })
                .error(function (results) {
                    console.log("error");
                });
        return {
            all: function () {
                return likes;
            },
            get: function (likeId) {
                for (var i = 0; i < likes.length; i++) {
                    if (likes[i].id === parseInt(likeId)) {
                        return likes[i];
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        };

    })
```

controllers.js (part):

```
.controller('OneCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Likes) {
  $scope.offer = Likes.get($stateParams.likedId);
})

.controller('LikedCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $http, Likes) {
  $scope.liked = Likes.all();
})
```

I've read articles and topics about promises, async(), callbacks, and $q but I have no idea how to integrate those things in my code, despite numerous attempts.

Comment: Your service needs to return a promise. Do not use `success` and `error` callbacks, use only `then`. Don't assign to any variable asynchronously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return promises from your service:

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])
.factory('Likes', function ($http) {
    // likes is a promise of array of likes
    var likes = $http.get("http://localhost:8100/js/offers.json")
            // then allows transforming the promise of http response into a promise of something else
            .then(function(response) {
                // transforms the http response into an array of likes
                return response.data.offers;
            });
    return {
        // all returns a promise of array of likes
        all: function () {
            return likes;
        },
        // get returns a promise of like
        get: function (likeId) {
            // then allows transforming a promise of array of likes into a promise of something else
            return likes.then(function(likes) {
                // transform the array of likes into a single like
                for (var i = 0; i < likes.length; i++) {
                    if (likes[i].id === parseInt(likeId)) {
                        return likes[i];
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
    };
});
```

And in the controller

```
.controller('OneCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Likes) {
    Likes.get($stateParams.likedId).then(function(like) {
        $scope.offer = like;
    });
})
```

Comment: I've copied your code, corrected ), }, ;'s, added LikesCtrl similar as OneCtrl, but it is not working anyway : (

        `.controller('OneCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, Likes) {
            Likes.get($stateParams.likedId).then(function (like) {
                $scope.offer = Likes.get($stateParams.likedId);
            });
        })`

Why've you put function(like), what is this 'like' for?

Also i don't get why do we call Likes.get two times in OneCtrl?

Comment: Sorry. Copy-paste error. Fixed the code of the then() callback.

Comment: Great, it's working now! Thx!
Although I don't get two things (i always get lost with javascript):

- where does the 'like' var come from? it appears inside the function(), but where does its value come from?

- how does controller know, that likes is a promise?

Comment: I suggest you read the following article, that I wrote, and which, I hope, will make promises clearer. But don't worry: they're a hard concept to grasp, and I had to try many times before understanding them. http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/. The controller doesn't know that likes is a promise. You, the developer, know it because you wrote the service returning the likes, and documented it by saying "this service returns a promise of array of likes".